# to Separate or not to separate try...catch blocks (best practice)

Tags: php, try-catch

Is it better to separate different try catch blocks, or can i group a series of class calls under one block? I have currently set to run with a single block and receive no errors. I am asking mostly for readability and future proofing.

for example, multiple blocks:

```
    /**  KERNEL AUTOLOAD
 * = check system setup and load autoloader, bootstrap, and magma config  */
try {
    /** AutoLoad Kernel */
    if (!require_once($paths['root']
        . '/' . $paths['framework']
        . '/' . '/kernel/core/KernelLoader.php')) {
        throw new Exception('Error - AutoLoader is missing');
    }
    $kernel_loader = new KernelLoader($paths);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo
        '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
        . $e->getMessage()
        . '<br />File: '
        . $e->getFile()
        . '<br />Line: '
        . $e->getLine()
        . '</p>';
}

/**  KERNEL BOOTSTRAP
 * = check system setup and load autoloader, bootstrap, and magma config  */
try {
    /** BootStrap */
    if (!$kernel = new BootStrap($paths)) {
        throw new Exception('Error - BootStrap is missing');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo
        '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
        . $e->getMessage()
        . '<br />File: '
        . $e->getFile()
        . '<br />Line: '
        . $e->getLine()
        . '</p>';
}

/**  APP SETUP
 * = initialize the app */
try {
    /** StartPage */
    if (!$app = new StartPage($kernel)) {
        throw new Exception('Error - App StartPage is missing');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo
        '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
        . $e->getMessage()
        . '<br />File: '
        . $e->getFile()
        . '<br />Line: '
        . $e->getLine()
        . '</p>';
}
```

Or a single catch block:

```
/**  KERNEL AUTOLOAD
 * = check system setup and load autoloader, bootstrap, and magma config  */
try {
    /** AutoLoad Kernel */
    if (!require_once($paths['root']
        . '/' . $paths['framework']
        . '/' . '/kernel/core/KernelLoader.php')) {
        throw new Exception('Error - AutoLoader is missing');
    }
    $kernel_loader = new KernelLoader($paths);

    /** BootStrap */
    if (!$kernel = new BootStrap($paths)) {
        throw new Exception('Error - BootStrap is missing');
    }

    /** StartPage */
    if (!$app = new StartPage($kernel)) {
        throw new Exception('Error - App StartPage is missing');
    }        
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo
        '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
        . $e->getMessage()
        . '<br />File: '
        . $e->getFile()
        . '<br />Line: '
        . $e->getLine()
        . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: I would prefer second options [single catch block ] ... grouping together and throwing errors. but for a few lines of code... not more than 66 lines

Comment: You can have multiple `catch` with a single `try` ([demo](http://codepad.org/9kTIAT72)), which is already better than the first example (imo) and if your `catch` blocks share the same logic, why not combine them? Maybe you can use a whole other method and do `catch (Exception $e) { Log::add($e); }`

Comment: @justrohu Yeah... thats what i was thinking as well. If the try is too long, it becomes unreadable, but otherwise, grouping is fine. especially if its a closely related set of tasks.

Comment: @kingkero I like that idea.. create a log class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entirely depends on, semantically, what the block of code is doing and how errors should be handled in terms of the business logic being performed.  (Not how they should be *caught*, but how they should be *handled*.)  For example:

- Are both of these operations part of a single atomic business operation?  In that case an error in the second operation may need to trigger a rollback of both operations as part of a single unit of work.  In that case it would make sense to handle them together.  (One `catch` block.)
- Are these atomically separate and distinct operations?  In that case an error in the second operation may have no logical course to affect the first operation and thus should be handled separately.  (Two `catch` blocks.)

Semantically separate out your operations into their own concerns, then handle errors within those concerns.

Comment: I like this answer. Very clear. The operations are in fact linked. One leads to the other, so grouping them is the best option. Thank you.

Comment: @obmon: Another thing to keep in mind with exception handling is that an exception should only be caught *if* it can be logically and meaningfully handled in that context.  If it can't, let the exception continue up the stack until something else can handle it.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me.. I'm building my own framework to teach myself OOP. You gotta go a little easier on me. What do you mean "in that context"?

Comment: @obmon: For example, let's say Function A calls Function B, which internally calls Function C.  If there's an error in Function C, you may not necessarily want to catch it there.  Not unless Function C can meaningfully *handle* that error with regards to the business logic.  You may want to let the error go un-caught until it reaches back to Function A which invoked the overall business logic operation.  Just remember the difference between "catching" an error and "handling" an error.  It's a common mistake to catch where it can't be handled.

Comment: Ah I get it.. thanks for that tip. At the moment, I am only outputting the data for debugging. But I will remember this when its time to extend the exception handling in my framework. Thanks again.